Using Column Headers with COUNTIF To Add those that Fall Between Dates in Cells
Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have dates as headers. They represent the classes people can attend, with a simple Yes or No in the respective column if they attended.
I am trying to come up with a formula in cell D2 that will give me a count of those classes they attended that fall after the dates in column A but before the ones in column B.
Column C is what the expected outcome should be. Column D is what my attempt was.
Here is the sample sheet (Question 2).
I would like to have one formula that populates the column entirely, rather than having to copy down the formula every time I need to add a row. It would also be nice for it to look past column N as I anticipate adding more classes in the future.
Clarification: The issue I'm seeing here is that it will only look at the dates in row 2 for columns A and B. Looks like the criteria for the filter function is not dynamic. It applies A2 and B2 to all rows.

The value in cells B2:B5 has an incorrect date ?

You are correct. Let me fix that. Thanks.

Restructure the Array First
Use the following formula:
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Arrayformula(IF((E1:N1>=A2:A9)*(E1:N1<=B2:B9),INDEX(E2:N9,0)))="Yes",1,0)), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))

This should result to:

Details:
The restructuring occurs in:
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Arrayformula(IF((E1:N1>=A2:A9)*(E1:N1<=B2:B9),INDEX(E2:N9,0)))="Yes",1,0))

Where it transforms the data in E2:N9 into ones and zeroes based on the dates condition and Yes/No condition. The restructured data should look like this:

After which, I applied the formula:
=BYROW(<array range>; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))

from this post's answer by player0.
NOTE: If the data expands:

E1:N1 should be changed if more dates are added.
A2:A9 and B2:A9 should be changed if more date ranges are added.
E2:N9 should be changed for data expansion.

Update:
I managed to use filter() for the expansion of rows. Here is the updated formula:
=BYROW(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Arrayformula(IF((E1:N1>=A2:A)*(E1:N1<=B2:B),INDEX(E2:N,0)))="Yes",1,0)),A2:A<>""), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))

Manually editing the ranges E2:N9 and E1:N1 is necessary for column  expansion.
References:

Index
arrayformula sum in Google spreadsheet


Should E1:N1 not be E$1:N$1 ? to make it always point to row 1, even if it is copied down.

I think there is no need to add $ since the formula uses the arrayformula() function. The user can just edit the range if the data expands.

This looks like it works but it is providing a value for cells beyond the dataset if I don't have a fixed number of rows. Instead of B2:A9 I need to use B2:A. Perhaps we can add something like IF(A2="","",FORMULA)?

The data will be expanding and frequently. The number of rows will expand more frequently than the number of classes (columns). So ideally, I'm looking for a solution that would account for expansion both ways.

It is possible. Let me work on that.

I have added an update to the answer. However, I encountered an error when expanding both rows and columns at the same time. What currently works is the row expansion.

That works. I can settle for just expanding it to many columns now. Looks like that works. Thanks!
